# Can we deploy / run a Windows Form app on Rasberry Pi?

Tags: .net, vb.net, raspberry-pi, .net-4.8

I have.NET Framework 4.8, Windows form app written in Visual Basic running on Windows 10 on a Desktop PC with MS SQL Server. Deployed the app in x64 and x86 archictecture. Both of them work correctly.

I am unable to find much support on how I can or if I can even migrate the app from my PC to a rasberry Pi and how?

The reason for doing this being high cost and power consumption of the PC and happy to explore different versions of Rasperry Pi so would highly appreciate any suggestions for different versions of Rasperry Pi or any other micro controllers (Arduino, etc) if seems suitable for the above mention technology!

I saw a bit of the Microsoft documentation and Raspberry Pi products. It seems like I would need to deploy my app for ARM or ARM64 architecture but my PC is x64 and both the deployments x86 and x64 work on this. Also, heard a bit about mono but not really sure if it works for Windows forms or what it actually is. Also, I guess somebody did do it using C# but doesn't have much info about vb.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy to arm or arm64 (which one you need depends on the version of Raspuan you have installed), but that works only for  .Net core apps, not for .Net framework apps. And also not for apps using Winforms. You might get it to work with the mono runtime, but that is a bit of try-and-error. You should find tutorials for this all over the place.

Comment: Thank you! I think i found a more appropriate SBC - Latte Panda Delta 3. Seems like it can run Windows 10 on an intel chip. I think its x86. But x64 would have been ideal for our app. Still need to verify though. So, .net app with sql server should hopefully be able to run pn it